# It's really necessary .addOnCompleteListener when you're using .setPersistenceEnabled(true) on Firebase?

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

thanks for curiosity !

I'm in doubt if it's really necessary to call `addOnCompleteListener` when I'm using `setPersistence(true)`.

When I use `addOnCompleteListener` , if my internet is offline, the screen keep loading because the `addOnCompleteListener` will never end - waiting for connection. So, I can't add anything offline because the loading screen is waiting for connection (breaking the concept of persistence).

Example below shows what I'm talking about :

```
getDatabaseReference()
        .child("Example")
        .child(userID)
        .push()
        .setValue(dataExample)
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()){
            //interface call with success response
            interface.onSuccess();
        }else {
            //interface call with failure response
            interface.onFailure(task.getException().getMessage());
        }
    }
});
```

So, as I said, if my internet is offline, I can't complete the action, the loading screen keeps loading forever (waiting for completelistener).

I figured out, that without `addOnCompleteListener`, I can add and remove values while I'm offline, because they're in cache, so when I have internet, the app send the updates to database online - that's brilliant.

The example below shows what I am proposing:

```
 getDatabaseReference()
        .child("Example")
        .child(userID)
        .push()
        .setValue(dataExample);

 //interface call with successful response without handling error (because it won't happen)
 interface.onSuccess();
```

So, my question is, it's right to do it ? 
It's a good practice ?
Without `addOnCompleteListener`, and stay able to use my app offline, sending updates only when able to ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are seeing is the expected behavior.  A write to RealtimeDatabase isn't considered "complete" until it reaches the server and becomes visible to other clients.  A locally cached write is not considered complete, until the SDK manages to synchronize it.  If you don't need to know when the write is finally received by the server, or if it was successful, then there is no need to register a listener with the Task it generates.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was thinking about it before you said it. So you did not respond if you consider good practice (user aber to use offline and send updates only when they have Internet access) - This data can be lost ? I've done some tests and nothing went wrong

Comment: The issue is not about best practices.  The issue is if you want to know what happened to the write when it was eventually received by the server.  If you don't care, then don't use a completion listener.  If you do care, then use it.  There is always a chance of loss, but you can't reattach a listener to a previous write when you no longer have the original Task available. There is also a chance that the write could be rejected because of a security rule.

Comment: Got it. You are persuading me to continue using the addOnCompleteListener :( - I don't think it's worth the risk..